# how to fix window is not defined in gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am making an app with Gatsby, but I have this error:

unexpected error while SSRing the path: /
ReferenceError: window is not defined.

```
  const activeIndex = () => {
    const found = routes.indexOf(
      routes.filter(
        ({ node: { name, link } }) =>
          (link || `/${name.toLowerCase()}`) ===  window.location.pathname
      )[0]
    )

    return found === -1 ? false : found
  }
```

Error is from these codes. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/), you just need to add the following condition:

```
typeof window !== "undefined"
```

Applied to your code:

```
  const activeIndex = () => {
    if(typeof window != "undefined"){
      const found = routes.indexOf(
        routes.filter(
          ({ node: { name, link } }) =>
            (link || `/${name.toLowerCase()}`) ===  window.location.pathname
        )[0]
      )

      return found === -1 ? false : found
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now is fixed but when I want to go in different routes I have problem. example: when I click shirts, and then contact, its 404: localhost:8000/shirts/contact. not direct in contact. any help ?

Comment: This is completely a brand new different issue. But for what you said, you are concatenating the URLs (first shirts, then contact, generating `/shirts/contact`). Just add a slash (`/`) at the beginning of the URL, like: `<Link to="/contact">` instead of `to="contact"`. If the issue has been solved please accept the question and if there are more issues, open a new question because it's really difficult to guess what's going on in 2 lines of description...

Comment: For dynamic links the approach is exactly the same. Check the relativity of your links and the slugs. Should be fixed with that besides being unrelated to the original issue

Comment: Thanks a lot once again Ferran.